# Enviar variavel através de função Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou aprendendo Jquery e apanhando que nem um condenado.

Criei uma função no arquivo js assim:

```
$(function abrir_qd1(variavel){
$(this).click(function(){
            $("#quadro1").load('arquivo.php?v=' + variavel); //carrega conteudo
});
```

});

e a função é chamado através de um link html:

```
<a onclick="abrir_qd1('var_enviada')" class="list_nome_aguard">click aqui</a>
```

E através de um alert eu descobri que o problema que a varivel chega na função assim:

```
arquivo.php?v=function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)}
```

Não estou sabendo lidar com isso aqui.

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 0, accepted):

existem alguns padrões juntos ai....
a primeira você vai usar quando quiser que a função seja chamada no load da página, sem ação de ninguem, então voce faz assim:

```
$(function(){
    alert('carregou');
});
```

Para voce declarar uma função, voce só declara ela o nome e a variável, desta forma ela aguarda ser 'chamada' por alguma ação, neste caso vc a declara no onclick do link assim:

```
function abrir_qd1(variavel){
       $("#quadro1").load('arquivo.php?v=' + variavel); 
}
```

Existe também a possibilidade de você utilizar o jquery para ter um seletor e uma ação e toda vez que ele encontrar o seletor e a ação ele executa, sem voce precisar utilizar a ação onclick por exemplo.

```
$(".algumaClasse").click(function(){
      $("#quadro1").load('arquivo.php?v=' + variavel); 
});
```

Se voce juntar as 3 nao vai dar em nada como ocorreu ai...

Comment: A função esta funcionando. o problema é quando ele recebe a variável ali na função 'abrir_qd1(variavel){'

Ele chega na função assim: 'function (a,b){return new p.fn.init(a,b,c)}'
Ele transforma a variavel em código

Comment: como ele disse acima esta bagunçado, coloque um ID na sua tag "<a>" e chame-o como na ultima forma que ele demonstrou no exemplo.

Comment: Entendi. Problema resolvido. Muito obrigado ae pessoal, estava colocando a função em local errado e por isso fiz toda aquela mistureba.